# "Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed" exception in spatie/async?

Tags: php, symfony

I am currently using `spatie/async` library in my `Symfony` project to perform asynchronous task. I have made a simple asynchronous function in my class but when I run the code, I get **Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed** exception in my output.

The code is as follows:

```
foreach ($datalist as $data) {
    $pool->add(function () use ($data) {
        $this->processData($data);
        echo $data;
        return $data;
    })->then(function ($data) {
        echo "then " . $data;
    });
}

$pool->wait();
```

The above exception only occurs when `$this` variable is accessed inside the `add closure`. But it works fine when accessed inside `then closure`.

I tried assigning the `$this` to another variable as shown below. But also produces the same exception

```
$that = $this;

foreach ($datalist as $data) {
    $pool->add(function () use ($data, $that) {
        $that->processData($data);
        echo $data;
        return $data;
    })->then(function ($data) {
        echo "then " . $data;
    });
}

$pool->wait();
```

Is there any work around for this? Also why can't we print any data inside `add closure`?

> UPDATE
> I found out that the above exception did not occur due to `$this` keyword. I created a task and added to the pool which seem to work. But when I injected some services in my task's constructor, the same issue exists.

Comment: Pretty sure I read this question earlier today... but posted by a different account.

Comment: Like... here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68188654/why-do-i-get-serialization-of-closure-is-not-allowed-in-spatie-async

Comment: @Raghu You don't have enough reputation to visit links to deleted Questions/Answers. Also, there's no point asking for an answer like that; if yivi could/wanted to answer, they would **by posting an answer.** That is a comment.